# Inner class __str__ calling from another script

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, methods

I'm working on 2.7.3 python. I have created one script with the `Layer` class, within it there is the `Sublayer` class. I modified the`__str__` method of the latter, but it doesn't take the modifications.

The code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

class Layer:

     class Sublayer:
        def __init__(self, mask, surface, height):
            self.mask    = mask
            self.surface = surface
            self.height  = height

        def __str__(self):
            print '\n    ---- Couche ---- \n    ----------------\n'

            cc = "  Surface de la couche : "
            cc += str(self.surface)      + "\n  Hauteur : "
            cc += str(self.height) + '\n'
            return cc   

        def __getitem__(self):
            return (self.mask, self.surface, self.height)
```

Then I have created another script, the tests script:

```
import numpy as np
from ClassLayer import Layer

l5 = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,150,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0]])

h5 = np.max([np.max(l5[i]) for i in range(len(l5))])
if h5 != 1:
    s5 = sum(sum(l5))/h5

che5 = Layer.Sublayer(l5,s5,h5)
print che5
```

So when the print is executed it doesn't take into account the new modifications I add in the `__str__` of `Sublayer`.

How can I write this code, keeping the two scripts separated if possible ?

Comment: Whoops, I made it in copying the code.
[Edit done]

Comment: Works for me. What do you actually see?

Comment: Note, although it's not the cause of your problem, nested classes are very rarely useful in Python; Layer should probably just be a module.

Comment: Well, it worked perfectly ... but, when I wanted to change the number of hyphens, it didn't see it. Here's what I did : I modified this number, then register the script, then run it and then run the test script. Finally, the modifitions are not shown

Comment: What do you mean "register the script"? How are you running this? Maybe your IDE (or whatever your environment is) is caching the old version of your `ClassLayer` module. BTW, since you're using Python 2 you should define your classes as being new-style classes, eg `class Sublayer(object):`. Otherwise, you get the inferior old-style classes (which no longer exist in Python 3).

Comment: Well, I know the low quality of it but I use gedit + ipython... So 'register' literally means it. Then, after typing "ipython" in the gedit terminal, I run it.

Comment: Did you fix the import statement in the test script so that it uses the new name?. Eg, `from ClassLayer import Sublayer`, and create the instance using `che5 = Sublayer(l5, s5, h5)`. If you're still having difficulties you should edit the question to show us your new code.

Comment: BTW, your `__str__` method is a bit strange: it should just return the user-friendly string representing the instance, it shouldn't have side-effects, like printing. Your `__getitem__` is even stranger: as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) say it's supposed to take a `key` arg. This method is used by container classes to implement indexing; it's not really appropriate for your class.

Comment: I also noticed that you don't define `s5` if `h5 == 1`; you need to fix that. Also, you can do those calculations more efficiently: `h5 = np.max(l5)`, `s5 = np.sum(l5)`.

Comment: Thanks for all you comments. I didn't know the np.sum/max : really useful.
Tbh, few weeks ago, python was totally unknown.
So maybe my methods looks strange but there is a reason : 1) the `__str__` "print" is just here to improve the reading of the output, 2) the `__getitem__` print is here to see when it's called : it is useless for now, I agree

Comment: So, like you said earlier, inner class aren't really "python" but, in my case, I thought it was closer to the data structure I'll use.
I still tried to put it outside the `Layer class`, the 1st problem was still there though. And there was another one : when I wrote `from ClassLayer import Sublayer` it raised me an import error like this :

`ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
  else:
      filename = fname
      __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)`